# how to mock npm uniqid for react unit test when using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm trying to mock npm uniqid library for react unit test. I have used this uniqid for check box. This is for component render test.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock it like this:

```
jest.mock('uniqid', ()=>(i)=> i + 'someUniqId')
```

or if you use one of the other functions

```
jest.mock('uniqid', () = > ({
  process: (i) => i + 'someProcess,
  time: (i) => i + ' someTime,
}))
```