# Testing nested components with Jest and snapshot returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, integration-testing

I am trying to create `SelectColumn.test.js` similar to `Summary.test.js`

https://gitlab.com/sosy-lab/software/benchexec/-/blob/SelectColumn.test/benchexec/tablegenerator/react-table/src/tests/SelectColumn.test.js

But unfortunately not successful, I tried all solutions from code forums. But seems I am doing something wrong.

> Result: failed
>
> Expected result should be: passed

Error:

> react-modal: No elements were found for selector #root.

```
      180 | 
      181 |   render() {
    > 182 |     ReactModal.setAppElement("#root");
          |                ^
      183 |     return (
      184 |       <ReactModal
      185 |         className="overlay"
```

**Edited on 01.03.2020:**

I added `<div id="root">` which fixed error:

> react-modal: No elements were found for selector #root.

but now new error is showing:

> TypeError: parentInstance.children.indexOf is not a function

in code:

```
      81 |           .create(<Overview data={data} />)
      82 |           .getInstance();
    > 83 |         const component = renderer.create(component_func(overview));
         |                                    ^
      84 | 
      85 |         expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
      86 |       });
```

I tried to move `ReactModal.setAppElement` to `componentDidMount` but it seems not to be the solution.

**Edited on 04.03.2020:**

Now I changed my code so it tests from the main component from `App.js` which works great, but I want to test just the child component `SelectColumn`. I tried with `shallow` and `find` but the snapshot is always `exports[...] = null;`

```
import React from "react";
import SelectColumn from "../App.js";
import { test_snapshot_of } from "./utils.js";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// mock uniqid to have consistent names
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538270/396730
jest.mock("uniqid", () => i => i + "uniqid");

const wrapper = shallow(<SelectColumn />);
const rootElement = wrapper.find("#root");
test_snapshot_of("Render SelectColumn", overview => rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `#root` is not an element in [SelectColumn](https://gitlab.com/sosy-lab/software/benchexec/-/blob/SelectColumn.test/benchexec/tablegenerator/react-table/src/components/SelectColumn.js)? but in your test case, you just import `SelectColumn` and want to do snapshot comparison? So I think **React-Modal** cannot work correctly in this context, because it cannot find `#root` element in this testing scope. I think Jest won't make the virtual Dom outside of `SelectColumn` for this test.

First, I think you can try to wrap a `<div id="root">` as the outmost element in the `SelectColumn` component to verify if the problem is like what I think. If it successes, then maybe you should consider adding this root element to this component, it also makes this component more reusable and decoupled (also I tried to find the `#root` [here](https://gitlab.com/sosy-lab/software/benchexec/-/blob/SelectColumn.test/benchexec/tablegenerator/react-table/src/components/Overview.js), but I cannot find it either, is it at more outside component? )

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for me:

`react-modal: No elements were found for selector #root.`

      22 | 
      23 |   componentDidMount() {`
    > 24 |     ReactModal.setAppElement("#root");
         |                ^
      25 |  }
      26 |   // -------------------------Rendering-------------------------
      27 |   renderRunSets = () => {

Comment: @Martin, sorry I was careless, this should be a problem of running test, updated the answer, hope it's helpful!

Comment: thanks this error seems to be fixed but now it gives me another error: `TypeError: parentInstance.children.indexOf is not a function`

 
 in line:   `83 |         const component = renderer.create(component_func(overview));`

Comment: @Martin, is this error in the test, too? Did you create an element with id `#root`? if you did maybe you can try to move your `ReactModal.setAppElement` to `componentDidMount`again, actually it would be better if you create another question and give more info :)

Answer (score 0):

When running the test, the reactModal DOM is not available so by filtering out for test cases, it wont set the #root element on null.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') ReactModal.setAppElement('#root');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I assumed the code is very self-explanatory. Perhaps I assumed wrong. I shall add some comments on the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than remove the modal for testing, [a suggested solution](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/632#issuecomment-378794979) is to move the `setAppElement` call outside of the testing scope of a project. I had been calling that in a "Modal" wrapper component but instead I moved it out into my entry `App.js` file (which never really runs for testing).

If you really need to test it though, you can do this:

```js
ReactModal.setAppElement(document.createElement('div'));
describe("test component that uses modal", () => {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im my case **ContactForm** is my component where i'm using model
below code helps to get rid of error while tesing

```
describe("test component that uses modal", () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    render(
      ReactModal.setAppElement(document.createElement('div')),
      <ContactForm> </ContactForm>
    );
  });
});
```